# Can I have a list of hide and reveal posts on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm using the following javascript to hide and reveal a sign up form on my website and it works perfectly for one form. The trouble starts when I would like more of these on one page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Hide the div
jQuery('#reveal').hide();
jQuery('.rv_button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery("#reveal").slideToggle(1000);
jQuery('.rv_button').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
});
</script>
```

The CSS is

```
.rv_button.closed:after {content:"\33";}
.rv_button.opened:after{content:"\32";}
```

I added the class 'rv_button closed' to the button that triggers the toggle and an ID of 'reveal' to the form itself.

I would like to use the same effect to hide and reveal a list of blog posts on one page but it's not working. I tried adding an ID to the buttons instead of a class because they're not unique items but that didn't work either.

Is there a way of tweaking the code to help me achieve this?

Comment: More of `"these"`? What do you mean? What doesn't work? If the blog posts are dynamic *(the result of an Asynchronous Event)* you would need to `.hide()` on those specific blog entry Elements as they come in.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have one form on my page using the script above and it works. Just as an experiment I tried to add three more forms on the same page but the reveal function wouldn't work on these.

On a different page, I would like to have a list of blog posts and I would like to show the title and hide the image and blurb. I was wondering could I tweak the code above to achieve this? I'm not familiar with javascript at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer without also seeing your HTML structure but you can create a wrapper for your divs. You can then check for which wrapper the button has been clicked and manipulate elements within that specific wrapper.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rv_button').click(function() {
    $wrapper = $(this).closest('.wrapper');
    $wrapper.find('.reveal').slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).toggleClass('opened closed');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper { margin-bottom: 15px; }
.reveal { display: none; }
.rv_button.closed:after { content:"\25BD"; }
.rv_button.opened:after{ content:"\25B3"; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="reveal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dignissim congue pharetra. Morbi neque urna, vestibulum vel fringilla ac, congue id risus. Cras tristique, ipsum ornare tristique lobortis.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="rv_button closed"></button>
 </div>
 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="reveal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dignissim congue pharetra. Morbi neque urna, vestibulum vel fringilla ac, congue id risus. Cras tristique, ipsum ornare tristique lobortis.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="rv_button closed"></button>
 </div>
 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="reveal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dignissim congue pharetra. Morbi neque urna, vestibulum vel fringilla ac, congue id risus. Cras tristique, ipsum ornare tristique lobortis.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="rv_button closed"></button>
 </div>
```